# Excel macro to move a row to bottom

Tags: excel, row, vba

Good day,

I am trying to create a macro that moves a row to the bottom of the sheet based on criteria.
What i have been able to do so far is copy the row to the bottom, but this will create a duplicate row for me, where in reality i only need it to be moved.

```
'Moving column "Grand Total" to bottom

With Wbk4.Sheets("TEST")
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'Loop through each row
    For x = 2 To FinalRow
        'Decide if to copy based on column A
        ThisValue = Cells(x, 1).Value
        If ThisValue = "Grand Total" Then
            Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 33).Copy
            lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("A" & lrow + 1, "Z" & lrow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        End If
    Next x
End With
```

Thanks

Comment: I also tried "Cut" instead of "copy", then to delete blank rows, but getting an error with this line. ".Range("A" & lrow + 1, "Z" & lrow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll"

Comment: Just a quick reminder that `Cells(x, 1)` should be `.Cells(x, 1)` when used within that `With ... End With` to ensure that the correct worksheet cells are being referenced.

Comment: if u use a reference (with block) , add the necessary `.` before every `Range` and `cells` !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've provided no sample data, it is hard to recommend a custom sort but a temporary helper column off the right side could quickly move all *Grand Total* rows to the bottom.

```
With Wbk4.Sheets("TEST")
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .Columns(.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Formula = "=--(A2=""Grand Total"")"
    End With
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion  'reestablish current region with new helper column
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(.Columns.Count), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
        .Columns(.Columns.Count).Cells.ClearContents
    End With
End With
```

There are two additional sort keys (maximum of three without doubling up) if you wanted to add additional sorting order(s).

Answer (score 1):

Try `Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete` or `Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 33).Delete` before `End If`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jeeped, it works fine !!
I Did it using another method before trying your code, and it works too!!
I am posting it below for reference in case anyone is looking for code references in the future

```
'Moving column B to bottom
With Wbk4.Sheets("test")
    FinalRow = .Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'Loop through each row
    For x = 2 To FinalRow
        'Decide if to copy based on column A
        ThisValue = .Cells(x, 1).Value
        If ThisValue = "Grand Total" Then
            .Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 33).Select
            Selection.Cut
            lRow = .Range("A" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("A" & lRow + 1, "Z" & lRow + 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next x
End With

'Delete Blank Rows 
Dim i As Long
With Wbk4.Sheets("test")
    For i = .Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If .Range("A" & i) = "" Then
            .Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Glad to hear you got sorted out. I added some standard indentation to your code for readability and prefixed some cell references with `.` to show their parentage in the `With ... End With`. When you start using `.Select`, the whole `With ... End With` can quickly go out the window but it should probably be there.